# Decomposition of Riemannian curvature tensor 4 dimensional manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request

I am looking for references regarding the decomposition of Riemannian curvature tensor into Ricci curvature, scalar curvature and Weyl tensors (both the self dual and anti self dual parts) in 4 dimensional manifolds.  I hope to find a reference that does not rely heavily on indices.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might wanna look at M.Blau's Lecture notes on GR.

Comment: Besse's *Einstein Manifolds* might be useful: section 1G deals with the decomposition in general dimension, then chapter 13 discusses self-duality in 4 dimensions.